# How to write one class reference variable in another class in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following C code fragment of stop and wait :

```
typedef struct 
{
     int data;  
}packet;
typedef struct
{
    int kind;
    int seq;
    int ack;
    packet info;
}frame;
typedef enum 
{
    frame_arrival , error,time_out
}event_type;
frame data1;
```

I want to convert the above C code in python. I am not sure whether I am doing it in correct way or not. The code in Python is as follows-

```
import enum
time = 5
max_seq = 1
tot_pack = 5

class Packet:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data

class Frame:
    Packet info

    def __init__(self, kind, seq, ack):
        self.kind = kind
        self.seq = seq
        self.ack = ack

class Event_Type(enum.Enum):
    frame_arrival
    error
    time_out

Frame data1
```

When I tried to run the above code then it is showing an error "Invalid syntax" in the line

Packet info

In addition, I want to know whether enum defined in the python code is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just treat `info` like any other variable in the class. No need to specify its type as `Packet`

```
class Frame:

    def __init__(self, kind, seq, ack, info):
        self.kind = kind
        self.seq = seq
        self.ack = ack
        self.info = info     # An object of type Packet
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, I am getting indentation error in class Event_Type. Is there any problem with enum in the code?